# Find the max and min value within each group

Tags: r

I want to find the max and min for each Gene in the following table.
I know, that the following function gives the max (or min), but I could not manage to get both at the same time.

```
tapply(df$Value, df$Gene, max)
```

Appreciate!

Small test set:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'Gene   Value
A      12
                 A      10
                 A      123
                 A      1
                 B      3
                 B      5
                 B      6
                 C      1
                 D      3
                 D      45
                 D      98
                 D      234
                 D      4')
```

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(Gene) %>% summarise(Min = min(Value), Max = max(Value))`

Comment: `range(x)` returns a two-element vector with the min and max values of `x`

Comment: `tapply(df$Value, df$Gene, FUN = function(x) c(max = max(x), min = min(x)))`?

Comment: `aggregate(Value ~ Gene, data=df, FUN=range)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
range()
```

Is the function that returns both the max and the min

Here you'd do:

```
tapply(df$Value, df$Gene, range)

# $A
# [1]   1 123

# $B
# [1] 3 6

# $C
# [1] 1 1

# $D
# [1]   3 234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using `tapply`, and simply modify the `FUN` argument to return multiple summary statistics. For example:

```
do.call(rbind, tapply(df$Value, df$Gene, FUN = function(x) c(max = max(x), min = min(x))))
#  max min
#A 123   1
#B   6   3
#C   1   1
#D 234   3
```